# Well-known stochastic process having constant variance over time

Tags: variance, stochastic-processes

Suppose that we have a stochastic process $v_t$ for $t=1,\ldots,T$.

Here, we do not impose any assumption of the serial correlation, but the constant variance assumption is required.

That is, the stochastic process satisfies $Var(v_t)=\sigma^2$ for all $t$.

Is there any well-known stochastic process that has constant variance?

Comment: Any stationary process has this property, e.g., the ARMA family.